# how to set tabindex order inside the component forms using angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

```
I have two components in main component html,

app.component.html



 <header></header>
    <left-component></left-component>
    <right-component></right-component>
    <footer></footer>
```

> in left-component i have one form & right-component I have another
> form,
>
> ```
> when using screen reader I want header to read first, second - right-component to read, I mean when i click on tab the cursor need to
> ```
>
> come to right-component, third- left-component to read, four
>
> ```
>     I cannot use focus directly, because tab need to go in flow from header, body, in body first component, second component, etc like
> ```
>
> that

Answer (score -1):

I think you could even achieve it without setting `tabindex` manually.

Simply put components in desired order in the template and then reorder them visually using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#the_order_property).